# Cloudformation : Autoscaling persist volume after instance stop and add tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloudformation template and using autoscaling in it.

I am able to persist my [volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) when I delete my stack, but I am not able to attach any tags to my [volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) via cloudformation.

Is there any way to do this ?

Or is it possible to create a [AWS::EC2::Volume](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) and attach it to [autoscaling group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) in cloudformation. I have also tried this but I am not able to do this.

Basically my objective is whenever an instance is terminated I want to persist the [volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) and the [volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-ebs-volume.html) must contain tags so that I can identify them.

The  following Cloudformation types I am using in my template :

[AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html)
[AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I came up with for doing this uses UserData when an Instances launches to

- [describe volumes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html), filtered by current instance id

```bash
VOLUME_IDS=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --output text --filters Name=attachment.instance-id,Values=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --query 'Volumes[].VolumeId')
```

- [create tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html) on the list of volumes

```bash
aws ec2 create-tags --resources ${VOLUME_IDS} --tags Key=YOUR,Value=TAG
```

A similar question is also asked on the aws developer [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=676689)